# Extjs 3.4 Grid's store undefined after reconfigured

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have an issue when reconfigure a grid panel. I have a EditorGridPanel which its store is built from a custom columnModel

After saving new settings (decide to show or not show some columns), I get a new store and a new column model, then I call `reconfigure` function to reconfigure the Grid, like this:

`grid.reconfigure(newStore, newColumnModel);`

The `reconfigure` function worked well, but when I click in the checkbox (CheckboxSelectionModel) to select a row, I see this error "Cannot read property 'store' of undefined"

I work on ExtJS 3.4.
On their API page http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-method-reconfigure, they warned:

> "Be aware that upon reconfiguring a GridPanel, certain existing settings may become invalidated. For example the configured autoExpandColumn may no longer exist in the new ColumnModel"

What should I do in this case to make the CheckboxSelectionModel work as before reconfiguring?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some debugging or provide where that error is happening. Please provide more information on that error.

I tried to reproduce but I cannot: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12rt

Comment: Thanks for your information.. After doing some debugging, I found that the code has created one more CheckboxSelectionModel, the error was caused by this new one. I updated code to not create a new CheckboxSM if it was existed, the error disappear now